# Is there a way to keep the order of cases as defined, while running bundle exec rspec {file_path} --format documentation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, bundle

I am having a problem while running

```
bundle exec rspec spec/services/abc_service_spec.rb --format documentation
```

The output of it, is not in the same order as the order of cases defined in the file.
Is there any option to pass with while running rspec command ?

Comment: It should be noted though that running your tests in a non-random order greatly increases the chance of test ordering issues popping up where a test only passes because the previous test(s) didn't properly clear up after itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-10/docs/command-line/order), Rspec uses the --order option to order the files, groups, and examples. The available ordering options are `defined` and `rand` while `defined` is the default options.

If somehow your Rspec order option has changed, then run the rspec with `--order defined` like

```
exec rspec spec/services/abc_service_spec.rb --format documentation --order defined
```

If you want to set it globally then add below code to your `spec_helper.rb`

```
Rspec.configure do |config|
  config.order = :defined
end
```

Hope you found this helpful.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. It was set to "random" in spec_helper.rb
`config.order = "random"`

Answer (score 1):

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/order

```
bundle exec rspec spec/services/abc_service_spec.rb --format documentation --order defined
```